# Latency optimization (DAC?)

Tags: hardware, ableton, dac

My Ableton shows that I have input and output latency = 11.6ms, so in total it's 23.2 ms. I think it's too much.
I'm using Focusrite Saffire 6 (usb 1.1) and I wonder if I should but sth with 2.0 usb...
**My question is**
What has a greater impact on latency: CPU/GPU or DAC (usb version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the ultra-low latency DACs are either Firewire or PCI, not USB.

Completely by coincidence, I was looking at Gearslutz yesterday & came across this
[Audio Interface - Low Latency Performance Data Base :](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/music-computers/618474-audio-interface-low-latency-performance-data-base.html)

There's far too much data to even try to summarise, & also 29 pages of discussion over the main post. I might try to squeeze some kind of précis into here once I've waded through it myself.

Comment: ok, thanks! I'm counting on you Tetsujin :)

Comment: if replacement of CPU could help I can handle this. I currently have i5-2300